# using lxml / xpath what are the various ways to select elements based on their siblings? (ex: only select <div>'s that follow <h1>'s)

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

For example, imagine many `<div>...</div>` blocks within an html page and want to select/find only the `<div>...</div>` which follows a `<h1>foobar</h1>`:

```
<div>not important </div>

<h1>foobar</h1>
<div>important stuff</div>

<div>not important</div>
```

This is a simplified example of a general question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would do it:

```
//h1/following-sibling::div[1]
```

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeah, I was just editing that as you posted it, hehe.  Misread the question.

Comment: Thanks Zenexer, NiklasB -- this works.  A followup question -- how can the XPATH be modified so only `<div>`s following `<h1>foobar</h1>` (filter on the string *foobar*) so `<h1>town</h1><div>..</div>` wouldn't match?

Comment: `//h1[text()='foobar']/following-sibling::div[1]`, though you might not need the single quotes.